# Is there a way to condense git branches into folders in IntelliJ?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-branch

For instance, I have several branches related to a single Jira ticket in a large repo. Is there functionality or a plugin I could use to break these branches up into individual folders on a Jira ticket level?

If not, I could work on a plugin,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean grouping by name in the branches pop, it is not possible in IntelliJ at the moment - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127468
AFAIK, there are no plugins doing this, as there are no extension points in the branch popup. 
It can be implemented on the platform instead of the plugin, though. A [pull request](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community) is welcome.